# Python function on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I need run the following function below on the lambda AWS:

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

# check if the partial sum is equals to target
if s == target:
    print("sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target))
if s >= target:
    return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    n = numbers[i]
    remaining = numbers[i + 1:]
    subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    subset_sum([1,2,3], 5)
```

However the following error appears and I can't resolve:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'LambdaContext'",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      7,
      "subset_sum",
      "if s >= target:"
    ]
  ]
}
```

The original function has more values that take a long time because of this I'm running on Lambda.

On the computer using py subset_sum.py it works normally.

Comment: Is `subset_sum` your handler function?

Comment: Please read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html.

Comment: Please show your entire Lambda function. If that *is* your entire Lambda function, then you should be coding your function to receive calls via a Handler. See: [Lambda Function Handler (Python)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handler function has 2 params event and context

```
def handler_name(event, context): 
...
         return some_value
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html